# How to make apache tomcat comes with netbeans installation work?

Tags: installation, netbeans, tomcat

I have installed the "apache tomcat" server came with NetBeans along with Glassfish server.

Now How can i deploy php application on it ? How should I configure it ?

The default directory of apache tomcat is : /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22
I have given full r/w permission to it.

In netbeans there is a home path setting which is set : /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22
and a base path, which points to a void folder at my home directory.

How I configure netbeans so that It can start and shutdown tomcat automatically ?

I have checked that I can maunally start tomcat and deploy application by copying apps to /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps directory. But all these needs manual labour.

How can I configure netbeans so that I dont have to do these manual steps ? How I should run applications ?

Answer (score 0):

To run php applications, you don't need a Tomcat server (see [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779246/342546)). Apache's httpd is sufficient (and, of course, a php environment) - see the [Netbeans documentation and recommendations](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html); there's even a [Ubuntu-related documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html).

You may [configure Tomcat to run a PHP application](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/UsingPhp) (AFAIK even Glassfish can be configured to host PHP applications), but i wouldn't recommend it if you don't have much experience with tomcat or glassfish.

Comment: I know. But Im habituated of using apache for php and glassfish for jsp. On windows 7 I had to configure nothing. Just install and Run. But on ubuntu Im having all these issues.